# Show $P_n A P_n \longrightarrow A$ in the strong resolvent sense.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Suppose we have a smooth domain $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the Euclidean norm and a self-adjoint operator $A: \mathcal H^1_0(\Omega) \to \mathcal H^1_0(\Omega)$ defined as $A = -\Delta + V(x)$ and a sequence $A_n = P_n A P_n, \ n\in \mathbb N$ where $P_n$ is the projection onto a space spanned by the orthonormal basis $\mathfrak D_n = \operatorname{span}(\phi_k)_{k=1}^n$. How can I show that  $P_n A P_n \longrightarrow A$ in the strong resolvent sense? I have been reading *Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics* by Gerald Teschl for reference. Strong convergence is defined there as:
$$
\operatorname{s-lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_{n}=A \quad: \Leftrightarrow \quad A_{n} \psi \rightarrow A \psi \quad \forall \psi \in \mathfrak{D}(A)
$$

Here is what I have so far:

Note that $i \in \rho(A)\cap \rho(A_n)$, hence it is enough to show that:
$$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\text { s-lim }}  (A_n - i)^{-1} \longrightarrow (A - i)^{-1}$$
We can rewrite this using Neumann series. So we want to show that:

$$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\text { s-lim }}  \sum_j (-1)^ji^{j+1} P_n(A P_n)^j = \sum_j (-1)^ji^{j+1} A^j$$

So we are ultimately interested in whether $P_n(AP_n)^j \psi \longrightarrow A^j \psi$ for all $j \in \mathbb N$, right?. I do not know how to proceed further from here. It seems it should be intuitive, but I am stuck.

***Edit:
Is it enough to prove this by induction? How is this?:***

By the dominated convergence theorem, we are able to move the limit into the summation (what is the dominating function?) and for $j=1$, we can now consider for $\psi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \|( P_n A P_n - A) \psi  \|_{H^1_0} = 0$$
Because the Fourier coefficients of $ A^j \psi$ are $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ for all $j \in \mathbb N$. Furthermore,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \|( P_n (A P_n)^j(A P_n) -  A^j A) \psi \|_{H^1_0} = 0$$
for all $j \in \mathbb N$, and we are done.

Comment: Where is this problem from? As is typical with unbounded operators, I think a lot of issues crop up immediately. For example, you presumably are using self adjointness to take $i\in \rho(A_n)$, but what is their domain? If the $P_n$ project onto some random basis, the nature of $A_n$ is not so clear to me.

Comment: @operatorerror This problem is part of proving that $\sigma( A_n) \to \sigma(A)$ where $A_n = A P_n$ and $A$ is the Schrodinger operator as described. The domain of interest is $H^1_0(\Omega)$., and the orthonormal basis I consider are Dirichlet eigenfunctions of the laplacian on $\Omega$. These results should show that the eigenvalues of the discretized operator in the well-known 'Expansion Method', made by the matrix $(A^{jk}_n) = \langle \phi_j, A \phi_k \rangle$ converge to eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Ah! If that's the orthonormal basis, then there is hope, I was worried this was just some fixed ONB, where there would be domain issues

Comment: It seems to me your original problem follows from combining lemma 6.36 and 6.38 of Teschl.

Comment: @operatorerror I see. Thank you. Do you think my approach works, though? It seems more direct than using lemma 6.36. 

As far as using the lemma, I see if I pick a set $\mathfrak D_0 = \operatorname{span}(\phi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, its graph under $A$ is dense in the graph of $A$, so it is a core. We have the result follows pretty directly, right?